# How i can check the full length of number even if it includes zeros?

Tags: r, string-length

i want to check the length of x that includes number like (600,000) it always returns length of 5 not 6.
i think R doesn't count if they more than 4 zeros like above.
i want know how to count the full length of x even with zeros.

Thanks in advance.

```
test_f <- function(x) {
  
  len <- nchar(x)
  
  print(len)
  
  if (len == 6){
    
    first_indx <- substring(x,1,3)
    first_val <- NUM20 %>%  select(ID,num_name_ar) %>% filter(ID == first_indx) %>% select(num_name_ar)
    
    second_indx <- substring(x,4,6)
    second_val <- NUM20 %>%  select(ID,num_name_ar) %>% filter(ID == second_indx) %>% select(num_name_ar)
    
  }
}

test_f(600000)
```

i tried the above code and were expecting to get length of 6

Comment: If you're not concerned about decimals like `600000.123`, then you can simply take the [`floor()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Round.html) of [`log10()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Log.html) like so: `floor(log10(x)) + 1`.  For `x <- 600000` then `floor(log10(x)) + 1` will give us `6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length isn't being given how you're expecting due to the fact R is converting the 600000 to scientific notation 6e+05. To avoid this you may want to add a format step at the beginning of the function

```
test_f <- function(x) {
  print(x)
  x <- format(x, scientific = FALSE)
  print(x)
  len <- nchar(x)
  print(len)
  
  if (len == 6){
    
    first_indx <- substring(x,1,3)
    first_val <- NUM20 %>%  select(ID,num_name_ar) %>% filter(ID == first_indx) %>% select(num_name_ar)
    
    second_indx <- substring(x,4,6)
    second_val <- NUM20 %>%  select(ID,num_name_ar) %>% filter(ID == second_indx) %>% select(num_name_ar)
    
  }
}

test_f(600000)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1] 6e+05
[1] "600000"
[1] 6
Error in test_f(6e+05) : object 'NUM20' not found
```